# Dynamically created mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript/jquery project that requires dynamically created labels used as a mouse pointer. Is there any way to change the mouse cursor to use dynamically created images?

```
var mybase64label = createLabelPNGBase64("Hello World!", "#ff0000");
$("#pagecontainer").css("cursor","url("+mybase64label+"), auto");
```

Comment: Try creating a `canvas` element , convert `canvas` to `data URI` , set  `data URI` of `canvas` to `url` of `cursor`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `url()` indicates that your `mybase64label` is in fact base64-encoded. It should look something like this `url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAASUh...)`

I'm guessing that this would work:

`$("#pagecontainer").css("cursor","url(data:image/png;base64,"+mybase64label+"), auto");`

Check out an example [here](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/DsAhE).